# Missing dependencies in latest rdfWebDeploy

Tags: json.net, dotnetrdf

I am trying to deploy a sparql endpoint using dotNetRDF to www.myapp.com/sparql.

`rdfWebDeploy -test` worked without errors but then running `-deploy` shows that there are missing assemblies in these tool.

First is complained about missing NewtonSoft.Json.Net35.dll, so I went into my nuget package and grabbed the dll in the net35 folder. However, this dll is named NewtsonSoft.Json.dll despite the 35 build...so I just renamed it has Net35 in the name and dropped it into rdfWebDeploy.

This worked so far, then it complained about MySql.Data.dll. I downloaded the MySql Connector which had the dll and dropped it into the rdfWebDeploy folder as well.

Finally rdfWebDeploy succeeded, however running the site produced

**Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json.Net35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.**

How can I get this tool to deploy to my Net 4.5 MVC site and get past this Newtonsoft issue? Also, how will I know my endpoint ("/sparql") is working, will it display something if I go there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tool hasn't been updated in a while and sounds like it has fallen behind the main code base somewhat, we haven't used the old .Net 3.5 builds of Json.Net in a long time nor do we have any dependencies on MySql.Data anymore.  So this sounds like a bug which we'll look to fix in our latest release - this has been logged as [TOOLS-424](http://dotnetrdf.org/tracker/Issues/IssueDetail.aspx?id=424)

In terms of what you will see when this is working it will depend on the configuration you have provided for your endpoint(s), a fairly default configuration would give you a query form such as the one seen on our live demo at http://www.dotnetrdf.org/demos/leviathan/ - you can see the corresponding configuration for our demos at http://www.dotnetrdf.org/demos/sampleConfig

#### Update

The mentioned bug has now been fixed and an up to date and working version of this tool will be available in the next dotNetRDF release currently scheduled for the end of July 2014.